# How to use one variable in regression with many independent variables in lm()

Tags: r

I need to reproduce this code using all of these variables.

```
composite <- read.csv("file.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
composite <- subset(composite, select = -Date)
model1 <- lm(indepvariable ~., data = composite, na.action = na.exclude)
composite is a data frame with 82 variables.
```

UPDATE:

What I have done is found a way to create an object that contains only the significantly correlated variables, to narrow the number of independent variables down.

I have a variable now: sigvars, which is the names of an object that sorted a correlation matrix and picked out only the variables with correlation coefficients >0.5 and <-0.5. Here is the code:

```
sortedcor <- sort(cor(composite)[,1])
regvar = NULL

k = 1
for(i in 1:length(sortedcor)){
  if(sortedcor[i] > .5 | sortedcor[i] < -.5){
    regvar[k] = i
  k = k+1
 }
}
regvar

sigvars <- names(sortedcor[regvar])
```

However, it is not working in my lm() function:

```
model1 <- lm(data.matrix(composite[1]) ~ sigvars, data = composite)
```

> Error: Error in model.frame.default(formula = data.matrix(composite[1]) ~ sigvars, : variable lengths differ (found for 'sigvars')

Comment: I've voted to close (and migrate to [so]) because this is really a question about R. That said, there are some interesting statistical issues here, not least the fact that you are looking into your data when deciding which variables to include in the model.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what `sigvars` is for a minute...?

After `sigvars <- names(sortedcor[regvar])`, `sigvars` is a *character vector of column names*. Say your data have 100 rows and 5 variables come out as significant using the method you've chosen (which doesn't sound overly defensible to be). The model formula you are using will result in `composite[, 1]` being a vector of length 100 (100 rows) and `sigvars` being a character vector of length 5.

Assuming you have the variables you want to include in the model, then you could do:

```
form <- reformulate(sigvars, response = names(composite)[1])
model1 <- lm(form, data = composite)
```

or

```
model1 <- lm(composite[,1] ~ ., data = composite[, sigvars])
```

In the latter case, do yourself a favour and write the name of the dependent variable into the formula instead of `composite[,1]`.

Also, you don't seem to have appreciated the difference between `[i]` and `[i,j]` for data frames, hence you are doing `data.matrix(composite[1])` which is taking the first component of `composite`, leaving it as a data frame, then converting that to a matrix via the `data.matrix()` function. All you really need is just the **name** of the dependent variable on the LHS of the formula.

Comment: I know, but what I do is save over the source file with a different product, so the dependent variable won't always be "Product 1." To accommodate this, I wanted to just always look at the first column in that data frame, rather than the name, which would require updating each time I load in a new file.

Comment: As I show you with `reformulate()` you can handle this nicely without having to force `composite[,1]` into a formula.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

`model1 <- lm(data.matrix(composite[1]) ~ sigvars, data = composite)`

The sigvars is names(data).  The equation is usually of the form lm(var1 ~ var2+var3+var4), you however have it as lm(var1 ~ var2 var3 var4).

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: The formula used is not `lm(var1 ~ var2 var3 var4)`. It is, *literally*, `data.matrix(composite[1]) ~ sigvars`. `model.frame` and `model.matrix()` will coerce `sigvars` to a factor and then try to build the model matrix from the data objects, whereupon it will find that `sigvars` contains say $p$ observations (the number of "significant" variables) whereas the response contains $n$ observations (the number of rows in `composite`) and that is why the error message refers to `variable lengths differ (found for 'sigvars')`.

Comment: Oh right, been using SAS macro variables for too long!